# Will Shimano Acera 8 speed derailleur work on 6 speed freewheel?

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear, speed

I want to get a higher quality rear derailleur from the Tourney which I have right now(it broke). I want a Shimano Acera RD-M360-SGS. The problem is that its 8 speed. Will it work on my 6 speed freewheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work, at least with respect to the crucial functionality of correctly aligning the chain with the frewheel cogs, because all Shimano rear derailleurs intended for between 6 and 9 gears have the same derailleur shift ratio (equal to 1.7), which is the ratio between the sideways movement of the derailleur and the amount the cable is pulled. This means that both the Tourney and the RD-M360 derailleurs will move laterally the same amount for the same command of your shifter, so both will correctly align the chain with the frewheel cogs.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I might also upgrade my 6 speed freewheel to 7 speed. When the derailleur arrives and it indeed works i will mark your question

Comment: Changing to 7 speed frewheel makes sense, especially because RD-M360 is actually intended for both 7 and 8 rear speed drivetrains.

Comment: as long as the new 7 speed freewheel is shimano, will it work with the new derailleur? Does it have to be an exact match?

Comment: Freewheels and cassettes are usually not made for specific derailleurs, so there is no "exact match" of the models; any Shimano MTB freewheel with a certain number of gears should work with any Shimano MTB derailleur intended for that number of gears.

Comment: @ΣτελιοςΛιακοπουλος Remember that if you increase the number of cogs, your shifters must be compatible with that (friction or 7-speed).

Comment: Just be careful about fake derailleurs online. In mid-Jan 2021, looking at Acera RD-M390 models, I found my search results to be full of fairly obvious fakes on Amazon and ebay. Many purchasers of those fakes reported shifting issues and other functional issues.

Comment: @VladimirF yep i will get new shifters too

Comment: @Armand thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Acera 8 speed derailleur works perfectly on 6 speed freewheel! A few days ago i also got a 7 speed freewheel and it works perfectly too! Thanks for the help